# Angular Bootstrap Datetimepicker disable date

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, datetimepicker

Below is a div where there is a datetimepicker.

```
<div class="dropdown" id="cal">
    <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" id="date" name="date" class="form-control" data-ng-model="environment.nextRun|date:'medium'">
        <span class="input-group-addon"><i  data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#cal" role="button" class="fa fa-clock-o dropdown-toggle"></i></span>
    </div>

    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <datetimepicker   data-ng-model="environment.nextRun" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown' }"></datetimepicker>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'm trying to disable the date and select only time. I have used disabled-date=true in the  tag but it doesn't work. Can anyone please help me disable the date and select only the time of a day? I need it in the format HH:mm

Answer (score 0):

To select time only, use:

```
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1', startView : 'hour', minView: 'minute' }"
```

`time` is not a valid value for minView.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout these links might be help full for you.

1. https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker#before-render
2. https://github.com/dalelotts/angular-bootstrap-datetimepicker/issues/123

**Try this**

```
data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1', minView: 'time' }"
```

Comment: `time` is not a valid value for minView.